# Efficient data structure for detecting duplicate values against another value

Tags: java, data-structures

Consider I have three columns of values as follows,

```
Col-A            Col-B            Values
1                2                9
3                4                9
5                6                9
1                2                8
5                6                8
3                4                7
1                2                7
5                6                10
1                2                10
1                3                10
1                4                10
```

So in the above set of values, (1,2) in (Col-A and Col-B) has all the set of values(i.e. 9,8,7 and 10) while others like 3,4; 5,6 do not have all the values. I want to obtain only **(1,2)** with the above data.

I thought of trying it using Hashtables, adding (ColA, ColB) to a separate object and using an Hashtable whose key is the object and value is the Column 'Values'. i.e.

```
Class K
{
    int a;
    int b;
}

Hashtable<K,int> numbers = new Hashtable<K,int>();
```

Adding every row to hashtable and when ever a duplicate Key is found, increment the count. Atlast check if the count is equal to the number of distinct values in the column 'Values'.

But am unable to figure out how to iterate for every value in Values i.e. 9,8,7,10. Is there a better way to do this.

[edit] After implementing dasblinkenlight's method in Java:

```
ArrayList<Double> list;
Hashtable<K,ArrayList<Double>> numbers = new Hashtable<K,ArrayList<Double>>();

while((line = brMyHashval.readLine()) != null)
{
    if(!(line.isEmpty()))
    {
        String[] temp;
        temp = line.split(" ");      
        eDouble = Double.parseDouble(temp[5].toString());                   
        Val key = new Val(Double.parseDouble(temp[0].toString()) ,Double.parseDouble(temp[1].toString()) );

        if(!(numbers.containsKey(key)))
        {
            list = new ArrayList<Double>();
            numbers.put(key, list);

        }
        else
        {
            list = numbers.get(key);
        }
        list.add(eDouble); 
     }
}
```

But the control goes to the 'if' loop every time. It never goes to the else part even if the Key is the same. In Java, an id gets associated with each key. So does it check for the id or the values in the object 'key'.

Iteration 1: key (id=52) x=1, y =2

Iteration 2: key (id=53) x=3, y =4

Iteration 3: key (id=55) x=5, y =6

Iteration 4: key (id=56) x=1, y =2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of an int, you need to store a list of values: `Hashtable<K,List<int>>` Add value to the list instead of incrementing count, like this:

```
var key = new K(a,b);
List<int> list;
if (!hashtable.ContainsKey(key)) {
    list = new List<int>();
    hashtable.Add(key, list);
} else {
    list = hashtable[key];
}
list.Add(value);
```

Comment: Just a note, the original question was tagged as java, not javascript.  Though if one translates your answer to Java (which isn't hard :) it is of course useful.

Comment: Thanks. But the control goes to the 'if' loop every time. It never goes to the else part even if the Key is the same. In Java, an id gets associated with each key. So does it check for the id or the values in the object 'key'.

Iteration 1:
key (id=52)
x=1, y =2

Iteration 2:
key (id=53)
x=3, y =4

Iteration 3:
key (id=55)
x=5, y =6

Iteration 4:
key (id=56)
x=1, y =2

Comment: I just came across this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485186/if-key-in-hashtable-is-a-class-object-how-does-containskey-work