# hashtable.get not working - java

Tags: java, hashtable

[image: The phone key which I'm trying to get from the hashtable]

The above picture shows the phone key I'm trying to retrieve from the hashtable. It's returning null where as the hash table does have that key as shown in following picture.

[image: This picture shows that Hashtable does contain the key I'm requesting in the above picture. But it's returning null. Why is so?]

Why is the hashtable returning null when it has the key. Please help I'm stuck from hours.

Comment: probably because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485186/if-key-in-hashtable-is-a-class-object-how-does-containskey-work

Comment: Post code in the question as text, not as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the .equals() method for your PhoneNum class.  Hash uses `equals()` to determine whether a key is equal to the parameter from `get()`.  Note that, if you write an `equals()` for your `PhoneNum`, you ALSO need to write a PROPER `hashcode()`, so it is not just a matter of writing equals.  Look up equals and hashcode so that you know what you are doing.