# Containment issues with HashTable class

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, equals, contains

I have an issue with the Hashtable class. I have a class TmpClass implementing a method equals. Then I create a Hashtable, and two objects of TmpClass being equal under my predifined equals method. Then I put of the object as a key in the Hashtable.
But when I test if the second object is actually contained in the Hashtable, the result is "false"...

Here is my main method.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Hashtable<TmpClass, Integer> list = new Hashtable<TmpClass, Integer>();
    TmpClass v1 = new TmpClass(1);
    list.put(v1, 1);

    TmpClass v2 = new TmpClass(1);

    if(v2.equals(v1))
        System.out.println("Equals");
    else System.out.println("Not equal");

    if(list.containsKey(v2))
        System.out.println("Contains");
    else System.out.println("Not contain");
}
```

Here is my TmpClass.

```
public class TmpClass {
private int val;

public TmpClass(int v){
    val = v;
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceof TmpClass){
        return val == ((TmpClass) o).val;
    }
    else return false;
}
}
```

It's clearly written in the javadoc that the method containsKey of Hashtable uses the method equals of the Object class to compare the keys. Does somebody have a explanation why then the inheritance property is not satisfied here? Or does somebody have an alternative way to solve this problem?

It would be very helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If key in hashtable is a class object, how does containsKey work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485186/if-key-in-hashtable-is-a-class-object-how-does-containskey-work)

Comment: Its there is HashTable's containsKey() code: if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing `equals` is not enough.

In order to use your class as a key in a `Map` you must also implement `hashCode`.

here is an example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Integer.valueOf(val).hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must also implement the hashcode method, as part of the [hashcode equals contract](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/). It's also stated in the [Hastable spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html):

> To successfully store and retrieve objects from a hashtable, the objects used as keys must implement the hashCode method and the equals method.